# How do I create a custom token in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, token

I need to create a custom token that can fetch a value from a mapping table based on nids. I need to know the hooks I should implement to create the custom token.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to implement [hook_token_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_token_info/7) and [hook_tokens](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_tokens/7).

The best thing you can do is download the [Examples module](http://drupal.org/project/examples), there's a module called `token_example` with well commented example code for how to implement tokens properly.